# Cake PHP 2.4.1: how to store fixtures in a subdirectory

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, fixtures

I have some code that I am migrating from Cake 1.3 to Cake 2.4.1, and I'm getting an internal error with one of my test cases. It's telling me that it cannot find the referenced fixture class. The fixture class I'm trying to reference is stored under a sub-directory: app/Test/Fixture/Ds1, which worked fine with the earlier version of Cake. Here's my test/fixture distilled down:

```
// app/Test/Case/Model/TestTest.php

<?php
class TestTest extends CakeTestCase {
    public $fixtures = array('app.ds1.test'); // Trying to load this fixture.
    public function testStuff()
    {
        $this->assertEqual(0, 0);
    }
}

// app/Test/Fixture/Ds1/TestFixture.php

<?php
class TestFixture extends CakeTestFixture {
}
```

And the internal error I'm receiving is `Referenced fixture class Ds1.test (Test\Fixture\Ds1.testFixture.php) not found`. I've been googling around for a while, and will continue to do so, but I wanted to ask here just in case somebody knows off the top of their head how to reconcile this issue. Chances are I'm missing something really obvious, but I'm spinning my wheels on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Inferring from the 2.x documentation, it looks like you can't have fixtures in sub-directories in 2.4.

From http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html

> As of 2.5.0, you can load fixtures in subdirectories. Using multiple directories can make it >easier to organize your fixtures if you have a larger application. To load fixtures in >subdirectories, simply include the subdirectory name in the fixture name:
>
> class ArticleTest extends CakeTestCase {
>      public $fixtures = array('app.blog/article', 'app.blog/comment');
>   }
>   In the above example, both fixtures would be loaded from App/Test/Fixture/blog/.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't migrate to 2.4.1 just like that.

Since it is a very old code (1.3) I would migrate first to 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I submited a pull request, you can find it here :

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/3005